# API for Powerpoint add-in (Windows and Mac)

Tags: macos, vsto, ms-office, office365, office-js

Is there a new API for developing add-ins for Office 2016 for Mac? I have seen a javascript API but I have not clear if this applies to Office for Mac 2016, Office for Windows 2013+ only or Office Web Apps only.
Please point me to an official documentation clarifying that.

Comment: I'm adding the tag for Office Java Script, which the Microsoft development team monitors. They should be able to tell you if and when it will be available for the Mac. I'm sure it's planned, just a question of when...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update, April 2016: MS recently made some announcements about Mac support at Build; primarily around Word & Excel. [Interactive chart similar to the image below](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability)

---

Eventually, but not yet. The only thing that is in for Mac is Outlook Read apps.

This is an image they've shared:[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CQvcIJsWcAIwBQg.png:large]