# Customized Excel in MAC?

Tags: macos, com, vsto, ms-office, office365

I have a customized excel project in windows. which i use it by installing vsto. Can i use the same thing in the MAC. As we all know that office 2016 is supported in MAC

Answer (score 0):

The MAC OSX does nor support the VSTO technology, so the answer is "No", I'm afraid.

Comment: office 2016 is supported in OSX. Still VSTO doesn't support in MAC?

Comment: That's correct. As far as I know, there are no plans to make VSTO available for the Mac. In contrast, the new JavaScript APIs to extend Office will (eventually) be available for the Mac. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648732/api-for-powerpoint-add-in-windows-and-mac

Comment: what to do with the javascript API? what i can do with it?

Comment: To make it precise, I have excel work which i customized . can i use that same excel work book in the MAC?

Comment: Can you use the same Excel workbook in the Mac, with the VSTO code:  the answer is NO.

Comment: The JavaScript API lets you build a UI interface with taskpane and (soon) Ribbon. It's basically the same principle as an ADD-IN (and is referred to as such since summer 2015). This is a good place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220082.aspx